# Excel - How to use the value of a cell as the row value of another cell in the data series of a graph?

Tags: excel, graph

Here is my problem

I have a value in the cell V4 and I want "=Sheet1!$B$12:$B$444" which is one of the data series in my graph to be changed to "=Sheet1!$B$12:$B$Value in cell V4" Does anyone have any idea how to go about doing this? I tried using the OFFSET function in the following way: "=Sheet1!$B$12:$OFFSET(B$1,V4-1,0)$" But that didn't work. I appreciate any help :).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to define the formula as a named range.

**1** - Open the "Name Manager" (Formulas ribbon, or ctrl+F3) and define a new name using your formula in the "Refers to" box In your case, that would be

```
=Sheet1!$B$12:$OFFSET($B$1,$V$4-1,0)
```

**2** - In your chart, edit the series data to refer to the name you want to use.  It must be qualified with a worksheet or workbook reference, eg "=Sheet1!mydataname". When entering a formula (here or elsewhere) F3 brings up a handy list of names you've defined.

**Update**

Here's more info on [Using named ranges to create dynamic charts in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-named-ranges-to-create-dynamic-charts-in-excel-HA001109801.aspx) (Note that this article referred originally to Excel 2003)

From Microsoft:

> [...] a series is generated by a formula that uses the SERIES function. SERIES is a special kind of function that's used only in this context, to define a chart series. You can't use it on the worksheet, and **you can't incorporate worksheet functions or formulas into its arguments**. [emphasis mine]

and

> By incorporating certain functions into the formula that defines a name, you can make that name reference different worksheet ranges, depending on worksheet conditions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't Think I understand. How would the name manager help if you define data sets the same way as in charts? I still don't know how to use the value in V4 in the name manager to refer to cell B444.

Comment: Did it not work or does it just not make sense? If it's the latter, I agree. A bug / feature of charts appears to be that they will not accept a formula as the the source for a data series (though I've seen some mention of them doing so pre-2007?) but they will accept references to ranges or names. I don't know why that is -- I'm honestly not a chart power user.

Comment: Sorry, I only just realised you made an edit :P. I tried `=Sheet1!$B$12:$OFFSET($B$1,$V$4-1,0)` But there was an error with the formula OFFSET was highlighted.